# Stable and simple amqp server for ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using rabbitmq-server as a amqp server with python client on Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit OS.

Rabbitmq-server now fails to start. I uninstalled and installed the latest rabbitmq-server 1.8.0 but still I could not make rabbitmq to work.

I want to other alternative with less learning curve to use the amqp on ubuntu system. Can you recommend one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAMQ
http://www.openamq.org/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting /var/lib/rabbitmq?

Answer (score 0):

**OpenAMQ is dead**.
The creators of OpenAMQ and of the AMQP specification are [dropping support for it in 2011](http://lists.openamq.org/pipermail/openamq-dev/2010-March/001598.html).

They suggest to **switch to [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)**.
I suggest the same. Take a look at the [ZeroMQ manual](http://api.zeromq.org/zmq.html). The messaging becomes really simple. Create a socket, do send.
No broker needs to be started. Applications use TCP addresses to specify the destinations.

The Python API uses the same functions.

Comment: iMatix dropping their support of OpenAMQ: Link is dead, here is an archive.org-link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160304094902/http://lists.openamq.org/pipermail/openamq-dev/2010-March/001598.html

Comment: Do they have push API?

Answer (score 0):

Why waste your time by installing and managing a local installation of a MQ? This is something that can be outsourced at a low price very easily to StormMQ, a cloud based AMQP provider. More here:
http://www.stormmq.com

Comment: thanks for suggestion. Cloud is too far by distance when the server needs to handle jobs in seconds or less than a second. I will look into strommq product.